# Отправка данных на сервер

Tags: html, mysql

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы форма, которую заполняет участник отравлялась на e-mail администратора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<textarea name="mess"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

**mail.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['mess'])){
    //проверки на правильность данных

    $admin_mail = 'your@email.ru';
    $subj = 'Новое сообщение';
    $mess = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mess']);
    $headers = 'From: site@mail.ru' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($admin_mail, $subj, $mess, $headers)){
        //сообщение было выслано
    }
    else{
        //ошибка при отправке
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="formmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name=recipient value="ваш@e-mail">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Сообщение с сайта">
```